# SQL Server 2012, Rank() & SUM() Over() Until condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I'm really confused on how to segment these groups into subgroups. This is an example of 2 orders (out of ~5M)

- An order may have 1 or more "grouped items".
- The group number = SUM(ItemQuantity).
- Groups are ordered by OrderLine

eg. In the below table we see one group of "3" & two groups of "2"

```
OrderNo  OrderLine  GroupNo  ItemQty
 10496      1          3        1     =3
 10496      2          3        1     =3
 10496      3          3        1     =3
 10496      4          2        1     =2(1)
 10496      5          2        1     =2(1)
 10496      6          2        1     =2(2)
 10496      7          2        1     =2(2)
```

Rank() & Dense_Rank dont solve the issue as there are multiples of the same group, OrderLines are different.

I'll be joining this to another table in the end but what I'd like is a way to differentiate the same groups. Perhaps by adding a "subgroup" field.

```
OrderNo  OrderLine  GroupNo  ItemQty  Subgroup
 10496      1          3        1        300
 10496      2          3        1        300
 10496      3          3        1        300
 10496      4          2        1        201
 10496      5          2        1        201
 10496      6          2        1        202
 10496      7          2        1        202
```

Testing below

```
   CREATE TABLE #temptable(  
       OrderNo varchar(5),  
       OrderLine int, 
       GroupNo int,
       ItemQty int); 

   INSERT INTO #temptable (OrderNo,OrderLine,GroupNo,ItemQty)
   VALUES 
   ('10496','1','3','1'),
   ('10496','2','3','1'),
   ('10496','3','3','1'),
   ('10495','1','4','1'),
   ('10495','2','4','2'),
   ('10495','3','4','1'),
   ('10495','4','2','1'),
   ('10495','5','2','1'),
   ('10495','6','3','1'),
   ('10495','7','3','2'),
   ('10495','8','2','1'),
   ('10495','9','2','1'),
   ('10495','10','2','1'),
   ('10495','11','2','1'),
   ('10495','12','2','1'),
   ('10495','13','2','1');
```

A DO WHILE

```
    SUM(ItemQty)Over(Partition by OrderNo,GroupNo Order by OrderLine) >= GroupNo
```

may work but it'll need to run for every group in every order.

I then started using XML path to query each line but it's really not going to be efficient.

```
    SELECT  distinct    t1.OrderNo,t1.GroupNo,
        STUFF((    SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(t2.OrderLine) 
                    FROM #temptable t2
                    WHERE
                    t2.OrderNo = t1.OrderNo AND t2.GroupNo = t1.GroupNo
                    Order by t2.OrderLine Asc
                    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE 
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,'' ) 
        AS [Rows]
    FROM  #temptable t1
    Order by t1.OrderNo,t1.GroupNo
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is the final expected output ?

Comment: in your example all orders have `10496` OrderNo, I think, they must be `10496` and `10495`

Comment: Isn't the unique group no just `OrderNo + GroupNo`? (concatenated as strings)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid the `Concat(OrderNO,GroupNo)` will group all `GroupNo` but we have multiple `GroupNo=2` on some orders. These need to be sub divided, which is where I'm having the issue.

Comment: So... order line 4&5 are one group 2 and order line 6 & 7 are the other group no? So we can always assume order lines group together (i.e. 4&6 are not one group?)

Comment: It seems you need a running total in item qty which breaks on group no (that allows for one type of group) but also uses mod `%` operator to auto-reset when the item count goes over the group number so you can recognise the next group. This way a one is always the start of new group

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes, Item groups are grouped according to OrderLines. It works for clerks but reporting the figures has my head spinning. Thanks for the insight, I'll look into the mod `%` operator. I haven't heard of it

Comment: and you can then use that _one_ in yet another running total to generate an artificial incrementing group number that only increments when it sees a one. Here's the reference for mod: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms190279.aspx

Comment: This is the 'inline' approach where you do it on the fly. Depending on your reporting complexities you might want to consider a data mart to pre process the data in batch

Comment: Thanks. This will eventually go into a SP and run on our nightly job. I'm currently looking at 2 years history so large batch may be a once off

Answer (score 0):

Taking @Nick.McDermaid s advice about the `mod %` here's a solution, admittedly it could be improved but for now it'll work out.

```
    With a as (
    select OrderNo,OrderLine,GroupNo,ItemQty
    ,CASE 
    WHEN SUM(ItemQty)Over
    (Partition by OrderNo,GroupNo Order by OrderNo,OrderLine) % GroupNo=1 
    THEN GroupNo*100 
    ELSE NULL END as SG
    from #temptable )

    Select a.OrderNo,a.OrderLine,a.ItemQty,a.GroupNo
    ,MAX(a.SG2)Over(Partition by a.OrderNo,a.GroupNo Order by a.OrderNo,a.OrderLine ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) as Subgroup 
    from 
        (Select OrderNo,OrderLine,GroupNo,ItemQty 
        ,CASE WHEN SG IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE SG+RANK()Over(Partition by OrderNo,SG Order by OrderNo,OrderLine) END as SG2
        from a )a
    Order by a.OrderNo,a.OrderLine;
```